# Flutter grey lines around expanded

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I am building a flutter web app, and I want to have a carousel slider widget with images. For this I use the carousel_pro package. I want the size to be the width of my carouselslider, which takes up the whole screen's width, and then set the size accordingly, to be the exact size needed. Is there a way to do this?
Now I am settling for a less option, which looks like this:

```
Flexible(
            child: Container(
              color: CustomColours.midBlue,

              constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: height / 2),
              //height: height / 2,
              width: width,
              child: Carousel(
                dotBgColor: Colors.transparent,
                autoplayDuration: Duration(seconds: 5),
                boxFit: BoxFit.cover,
                images: [
                  AssetImage(
                      'lib/assets/create-esports-poster-design-in-48-hours.png'),
                  //AssetImage('lib/assets/Image from iOS.jpg'),
                  // AssetImage('lib/assets/banner.png'),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

And I know I could not add a height for a container for it to work, but since this is in a column, it has to have a height. This solution would be good for me, however now the slider has grey lines on top and below it, like this: [image] Is there a way to 1) do what I originally wanted or 2) fix this issue? Thank you very much!